# SQL SELECT. Involving COUNT

Tags: sql

So I have 3 tables. One with the `Id` and `Name`, the second one with `Id` and some other stuff which is not relevant in here and the third table with it's own `Id`, `table1Id` and `table2Id` (table1 and table2 does not know anything about each other). I want to `SELECT` the following. `Id` and `Name` from the `table1` and the count of `table2Id`s from `table3` which would be grouped by `table1Id`. How can I do that. I'm pretty new to `SQL` so any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance. If needed I can provide more details.

Comment: Mistake that I was making was that I was grouping by just Table1.Id, I had to group it with the Id and the Name as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Table1.ID,
    Table1.Name,
    COUNT(Table3.Table2ID) AS Table2IDCount
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.Table1ID
GROUP BY
    Table1.ID,
    Table1.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1(id int, name nvarchar(20))

insert into table1 values(1, 'Value 1')
insert into table1 values(2, 'Value 2')
insert into table1 values(3, 'Value 3')

create table test1(id int, table1id int, table2id int)

insert into test1 values(1,1,1)
insert into test1 values(2,1,2)
insert into test1 values(3,1,3)
insert into test1 values(4,1,4)
insert into test1 values(5,1,5)
insert into test1 values(6,2,1)
insert into test1 values(7,2,2)
insert into test1 values(8,2,3)
insert into test1 values(9,2,4)
insert into test1 values(10,2,5)
insert into test1 values(11,3,1)
insert into test1 values(12,3,2)
insert into test1 values(13,3,3)
insert into test1 values(14,3,4)
insert into test1 values(15,3,5)


select n.id, n.name, count(distinct(table2id)) [Count]
from test1 t
inner join table1 n on (t.table1id = n.id)
group by n.id, n.name
order by 1
```